# How does integer type cast behave in Java for numbers beyond the range of integers?

Tags: java, casting

Here is my program.

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println((int) 2147483648l);
        System.out.println((int) 2147483648f);
    }
}
```

Here is the output.

```
-2147483648
2147483647
```

Why isn't `2147483648l` and `2147483648f` type cast to the same integer? Can you explain what is going on here or what concept in Java I need to understand to predict the output of type casts like these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Java integer-type primitive casts "capped" at the MAX\_INT of the casting type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641559/are-java-integer-type-primitive-casts-capped-at-the-max-int-of-the-casting-typ)

Comment: No, that's only a dupe for 1/2 the question. Best to answer with that excellent question as a reference, which is what I have tried to do.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

These are examples of the [Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) operation.

In your first example, `long` to `int`:

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

So your `(int) 2147483648l` is taking the 64 bits of the `long`:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

...and dropping the top 32 bits entirely:

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

...and taking the remaining 32 bits as an `int`. Since the leftmost of those is now a sign bit (`long` and `int` are stored as two's complement), and since it happens to be set in your `2147483648l` value, you end up with a negative number. Since no other bits are set, in two's complement, that means you have the lowest negative number `int` can represent: -2147483648.

The `float` to `int` example follows a more complex rule. The relevant parts for your value are:

> ...if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3).
>
> ...[if] the value [is] too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), [then] the result of the first step is the largest representable value of type int or long.

*(But see the part of the spec linked above for the details.)*

So since `2147483648f` rounds to `2147483648`, and `2147483648` is too large to fit in `int`, the largest value for `int` (`2147483647`) is used instead.

So in the `long` to `int`, it's bit fiddling; in the `float` to `int`, it's more mathematical.

---

In a comment you've asked:

> Do you know why both `(short) 32768` and `(short) 32768f` evaluate to `-32768`? I was exepecting the latter to evaluate to `32767`.

Excellent question, and that's where my *"see the part of the spec linked above for the details"* above comes in. :-) `(short) 32768f` does, in effect, `(short)(int)32768f`:

In the spec section linked above, under "A narrowing conversion of a floating-point number to an integral type T takes two steps:", it says

> 1. In the first step, the floating-point number is converted either to a `long`, if T is `long`, or to an `int`, if T is `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`...

and then later in Step 2's second bullet:

> 2. * If T is `byte`, `char`, or `short`, the result of the conversion is the result of a narrowing conversion to type T (§5.1.3) of the result of the first step.

So in step one, `32768f` becomes `32768` (an `int` value), and then of course `(short)32768` does the bit-chopping we saw in `long` => `int` above, giving us a `short` value of `-32768`.

Comment: A wonderful answer. Upvoted - we don't want the OP to be tempted to accept mine.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Why don't we want that? It's simple and clear. :-)

Comment: Does this apply to other languages? c#?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Do you know why both `(short) 32768` and `(short) 32768f` evaluate to `-32768`? I was exepecting the latter to evaluate to `32767`.

Comment: @LoneLearner: Excellent question, I've explained it in a new bit at the end of the answer above.

Comment: @MarioGarcia: No. Each language defines its own semantics around this. In C#, both of the casts in the question result in `-2147483648` (and both require an `unchecked` wrapper).

Answer (score 20):

Nice! It's wonderful to see the effects of design decisions presented in the way that you have.

`2147483648l` is a `long` type and the *rule* for converting a `long` that's too big for the `int` is to apply the *wrap-around* rule into the destination type. (Under the hood, the significant bits from the source type are simply discarded.)

`2147483648f` is a `float` type and the *rule* for converting a `float` that's too big for the destination type is to take the largest possible for the destination type. Reference [Are Java integer-type primitive casts "capped" at the MAX_INT of the casting type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641559/are-java-integer-type-primitive-casts-capped-at-the-max-int-of-the-casting-typ)

The good thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from.

Comment: At least the behaviour is fully defined in the language spec and not left to the implementations.

Comment: @biziclop: which personally I see as a shortcoming - you probably have to burn the living daylights out of the CPU of an "exotic" architecture so it conforms to this.

Comment: @Bathsheba Depends on where you're coming from. For me it's infinitely better than getting a different result, because I don't care much how difficult it is to create the VM. But if your job is exactly that, I can see how the strict specification is a bit of a pain. Though not necessarily in this area, as this is a vanishingly rare scenario, more in the "everything has to be big endian" rule.

Comment: @Bathsheba: A better approach IMHO would be to have a wider range of types defined in the language, many of which would typically be aliases for a smaller number of types, *but* with the exact set of types varying depending upon the implementation.  Have some types whose behavior is rigidly specified in implementation-independent fashion, and some others whose behavior could vary according to what an implementation finds convenient.  Code needing a specific behavior could use types which are guaranteed to provide it, while code with looser requirements could give implementations more freedom.

Comment: @supercat of course, having a large range of types with lots of small semantic differences is just asking for trouble... remember developers are the same people who regularly fail to write `for loops` correctly.  As such even better approach would be to leave the very small portion of performance critical code running on exotic infrastructure to an entirely different language suited for such peculiarities and connect to it via some sort of Native Interface ;)

Comment: @NPSF3000: Code that doesn't need optimal performance could use types whose behavior is guaranteed consistent on all platforms.  Being able to also have types that behave more efficiently for use when their semantics will suffice would be a useful adjunct.

Comment: @supercat Sure, we could put all that work and effort in (language design, compiler design, framework support etc)... so that your day to day developer can do a micro-optimization in rarely run code that fails in a rare, critical and random manner.  Fair enough, each to their own.  I prefer that effort put into `async` or `lambda` or `LINQ` or `string interpolation` or `generics` or `pattern matching` etc.  Features that can be used by most developers on every platform.

Comment: @NPSF3000: A major part of getting good performance is being able to specify the semantics one needs, without forcing the implementation to expend effort providing semantics one doesn't.  Further, if a language guarantees that `x*y > z` will perform a "wrapping" computation of `x*y` someone *reading* the code will have no idea whether the programmer cares whether the programmer would mind if the compiler might sometimes use the non-wrapping arithmetical value of `x` times `y`, or might generate code with unconstrained arbitrary side-effects in case of overflow.  Having ways by which...

Comment: ...the programmer could specify such things would make clearer whether the possibility of overflow would indicate a bug, or whether the overall operation of the program would work fine if overflows result in the comparison arbitrarily yielding 0 or 1 *but have no other side-effect*.  The more accurately a programmer can indicate what's needed, the more effectively a compiler will meet those precise needs, and the more readily programmers reviewing the code will be able to know how the author expected it to behave.

Comment: @supercat sure, a language needs to allow a programmer to express the semantics one needs.  However, do not confuse that with allowing the developer to get caught up in semantics one does not need, while diverting resources from developing features that do help the developer.  Take generics... how many Java developers do you think use generics on a daily basis, as opposed to Java developers wondering about the merits of 'unconstrained arbitrary side-effects in case of overflow' vs 'non-wrapping arithmetical value'?  Where would you spend your time/money/effort/compatibility budget?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138744/discussion-between-npsf3000-and-supercat).